# What happened to the Death Eaters after the Battle of Hogwarts?

Tags: harry-potter, death-eaters

What happened to the Death Eaters after the Battle of Hogwarts?

Were they pardoned?

Imprisoned?

Stripped of their positions at the Ministry?

Have they fled from Great Britain?